# jdk17 ThreadPoolExecutor corePoolSize can't run to maximum

Tags: kotlin, threadpool

I have 2 ThreadPoolExecutor,
outerThreadPoolExecutor used to commit task to innerThreadPoolExecutor,when run this code, corePoolSize can run up to 700,but after a while it dropped to 36.

The server has two CPUs, each with 14 cores and 28 threads.
Can jdk automatically optimize the number of threads? Or what causes the problem?

I want to solve the problem that corePoolSize has too few active threads.

```kotlin
 val max = 10
val outerThreadPoolExecutor = ThreadPoolExecutor(
                max,
                max,
                10,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                LinkedBlockingQueue(),
                DefaultThreadFactory("outer-thread-pool")
            )
 val innerThreadPoolExecutor =  ThreadPoolExecutor(
                                700,
                                700,
                                10,
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                LinkedBlockingQueue(),
                                DefaultThreadFactory("inner-"+Thread.currentThread().name)
                            )
```

```
[2023-09-01 11:11:49]outer:java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e768678[Shutting down, pool size = 10, active threads
 = 10, queued tasks = 9984, completed tasks = 6]
[2023-09-01 11:11:49]inner:java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@b169c6[Running, pool size = 700, active threads = 700
, queued tasks = 78149, completed tasks = 0]


[2023-09-01 11:14:35]outer:java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e768678[Shutting down, pool size = 10, active threads
 = 10, queued tasks = 9612, completed tasks = 378]
[2023-09-01 11:14:35]inner:java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@b169c6[Running, pool size = 700, active threads = 36,
 queued tasks = 499796, completed tasks = 4500149]
```

Comment: *"Or what causes the problem?"* - Why is it a problem?  What do you achieve by having more "active" threads than (hypothetically) can actually run?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: openjdk version "17.0.2",There are too many tasks, so I want to open more threads to execute, so as to complete the program faster

Comment: Erm ... if the tasks are CPU intensive (i.e. won't block on I/O or synchronization with other tasks) then adding more worker threads will not make the application run faster.  You have 14 cores / 28 hyperthreads so the number of workers that can actually execute at the same time is 28.

Comment: Having said that, since you appear to have set both the core and max threadpool size to 700, so the pool size ought to stay at 700.  However, it looks like if a task exits due to an uncaught exception, that causes the worker to terminate too.  (This is based on a rough reading of the OpenJDK 17 source code.)

Comment: That's not Java code.

Comment: What is the result of [`allowsCoreThreadTimeOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowsCoreThreadTimeOut())?

Comment: That is kotlin code,But it doesn't matter. allowsCoreThreadTimeOut() I look at the source code and the default is false,And then I'll test it on the program.

Comment: And I'll add a try cache block and test it later.

Comment: If you want an answer that gives a definite explanation of what you are seeing, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  And you ought to tag your questions correctly.  Kotlin questions should not be tagged `[java]` or `[java]` questions shouldn't contain Kotlin example code.  They are different programming languages.  A Java expert may not read Kotlin and *vice versa*.  (And don't tell us it doesn't matter!)

Comment: OK,Thanks for reminding me.I corrected it.

Comment: After testing, I found that each task  executed quickly,execution time may be wasted switching threads or reading queue tasks into the thread

Answer (score 0):

### `allowsCoreThreadTimeOut()`

> Can jdk automatically optimize the number of threads?

The documentation says that threads in the pool exceeding `corePoolSize` can time-out and terminate.

Apparently you expect that since your code specifies the same number for `corePoolSize` and for `maximumPoolSize` (10 & 10, 700 & 700) then you should never see the count of threads in your pool shrink, to not go below the `corePoolSize`.

That behavior letting even the “core” threads time-out **may or may not be in effect**, depending on the value returned by [`allowsCoreThreadTimeOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowsCoreThreadTimeOut()).

- If `false`, then the count of active threads in your two pools should indeed always be unchanged, at 10 and at 700.
- On the other hand, if `true`, then the count of active threads in your two pools may change, if their time-out expires.

You can test this behavior change in your code. Call [`ThreadPoolExecutor#allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)) to disable or enable the behavior.

### Virtual threads

By the way, 700 is likely an unreasonable number of threads in Java today on a machine of 56 hyper-threaded cores / 28 real cores.

Before Java 21, all Java threads are actually one-to-one mapped onto threads provided by the host OS, “platform threads”. These platform threads are expensive. The usual rule of thumb for a pool size is more like the number of cores on the machine, or less.

If your tasks involve blocking code (quite likely), then you should consider switching to [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) in [Java 21+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21). Virtual threads are vastly cheaper, and are efficiently managed and scheduled by the JVM rather than the host OS. A million virtual threads running is reasonable.

When using virtual threads, there is no need for a thread pool. Just assign one thread per task, letting the thread terminate on the single task’s completion. For example, use `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()` as your executor service.

Here is an example app where we use virtual threads in an executor service to perform 10 tasks, each task performing 700 sub-tasks in another executor service of virtual threads.

Notice how we do not need to maintain an executor service. We create an executor service of virtual threads, use it, and let it close via try-with-resources syntax.

And notice how we need no pool of threads. A new virtual thread is created per outer task, and per inner task.

```java
package work.basil.example.vthreads;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            // Generate and submit 10 "Outer" tasks.
            Collection < Outer > tasks =
                    IntStream
                            .rangeClosed ( 1 , 10 )
                            .mapToObj ( ( int i ) -> new Outer ( ) )
                            .toList ( );
            List < Future < Instant > > futures = executorService.invokeAll ( tasks );
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
    }
}

class Outer implements Callable < Instant >
{
    @Override
    public Instant call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            // Generate and submit 700 "Inner" tasks.
            Collection < Inner > tasks =
                    IntStream
                            .rangeClosed ( 1 , 700 )
                            .mapToObj ( ( int i ) -> new Inner ( ) )
                            .toList ( );
            List < Future < Instant > > futures = executorService.invokeAll ( tasks );
            // Report
            Instant now = Instant.now ( );
            System.out.println (
                    "Of 700 tasks run at " + now + "\n"
                            + futures.stream ( ).filter ( Future :: isCancelled ).count ( ) + " were cancelled,\n"
                            + futures.stream ( ).filter ( Future :: isDone ).count ( ) + " were done.\n"
            );
            return now;
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
    }
}

class Inner implements Callable < Instant >
{
    @Override
    public Instant call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        //System.out.println ( "DEBUG - starting `call` on `Inner`. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        //Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 200 , 900 ) ) ); // Pretend to do work.
        return Instant.now ( );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.103428Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.105357Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.111467Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.098020Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.107053Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.105033Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.111884Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.100919Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.102849Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.

Of 700 tasks run at 2023-09-03T07:21:52.112211Z
0 were cancelled,
700 were done.
```